# Springframework: Is there a way to handle NoSuchBeanDefinitionException?

Tags: spring, testing, dependency-injection

As you might imagine, this is for unit/integration testing. Basically I want to be able handle
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException and provide the object/bean at request.

Comment: Might be a better idea to use different bean profiles for your tests instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are solving the wrong problem. Somewhere in your code/configuration you state that a particular bean should exist. If that bean does not exist, the framework is correctly complaining. Either your initial assertion that the bean should exist is correct, in which case you need to provide it, or the assertion is wrong.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'provide the object/bean at request' since you don't provide anything. The `ApplicationContext` is either aware of it or not, at which point you don't provide it. The only decision is whether it provides a singleton/prototype or whether it creates it eagerly/lazily.

Comment: I know, I was just brainstorming. There is this interface `FactoryBean`, what I wanted was to create a GenericFactoryBean so it could provide all the mocks when spring asked for it or recover from NoSuchBeanDefinitionException, either way did not work or make sense. Thanks.